# I have started making a bot in discord but the bot is not sending dms to the members of the server

Tags: python-3.x, discord, bots, discord.py

I have been running the following code and after various changes the bot still never returns an welcome dm to the user, even after making sure that the permission to message users from the server is enabled.

```
import os
import discord

from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')# gets the token of the bot from the .env file

client = discord.Client()# makes and discord client

@client.event #client on the following event:
async def on_ready():
        print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')# tells us if the bot is connected
        
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.create_dm()# creates an dm channel
    await member.dm_channel.send( # sends the string given as argument to the channel created
        f'Hiiiiiiiiiii {member.name}, welcomeeeeeeeee icyyyyyy here'
    )

client.run(TOKEN)# runs client for the bot token in TOKEN
```

And the code successfully returns that the bot is connected to discord and also comes online in the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable `dm` intents (there are quite a few so I suggest you enabling default intents) and `intents.members`

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Don't forget to enable privileged member intents in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

Also `dm_channel` can be `None` if it's not created, here's a better solution

```
await member.send('whatever')
```